# How could I render a ExtWebComponent Area Chart using Alpha Vantage stock data?

Tags: extwebcomponents

I would like to use Alpha Vanatage stock data in my ExtWebComponent chart. How could I fetch the data and render it in a Cartesian Area chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've generated an ExtWebComponents project, you could add these 2 files and declare the web component html element tag.

[image: This is how it could look]

**Usage**

In the html file like index.html declare `my-chart-area` which is defined in the web component below.

**AreaChartComponent.html - HTML Template**

```
<ext-cartesian 
  width="1000px"
  height="600px"
  downloadServerUrl="http://svg.sencha.io" 
  shadow="true"
  insetPadding="25 35 0 10"
  axes='[{
          "type": "numeric" ,
          "position": "left" ,
          "fields": [ "1. open" ],
          "label": { "rotate": { "degrees": "-30" } },
          "grid": { "odd": { "fill": "#e8e8e8" } },
          "title": { "text": "Alphabet Inc Stock Data" , "fontSize": "20" }
      },
      {
          "type": "category",
          "position": "bottom",
          "fields": "time",
          "grid": "true",
          "title": { "text": "Monthly", "fontSize": "20" }
    }]'
    legend='{
      "type": "sprite",
      "position": "bottom"
    }'
    series='[{
      "type": "area" ,
      "xField": "time",
      "yField": [ "1. open", "2. high", "3. low", "4. close" ],
      "title": [ "open", "high", "low", "close" ],
      "style": { "stroke": "black" , "lineWidth": "2", "fillOpacity": "0.8" },
      "colors": ["#003f5c", "#58508d", "#bc5090", "#ff6361", "#ffa600"]
    }]' 
    platformConfig='{
      "phone": { "insetPadding": "15 5 0 0" }
    }'>
</ext-cartesian>
```

**AreaChartComponent.js - Web Component**

```
import template from './AreaChartComponent.html'

Ext.require([
  'Ext.chart.theme.Midnight',
  'Ext.chart.theme.Green',
  'Ext.chart.theme.Muted',
  'Ext.chart.theme.Purple',
  'Ext.chart.theme.Sky',
  'Ext.chart.series.Area',
  'Ext.chart.axis.Numeric',
  'Ext.chart.axis.Category'
]);

class AreaChartComponent extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = template;

    this._fetchChartData();
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
  }

  /**
   * Fetch the chart data from https://www.alphavantage.co/ using an API Key. 
   * 
   * TODO Fetch your api key here: https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key 
   */
  _fetchChartData() {
    let me = this;
    let apiKey = 'demo'; 
    let stockSymbol = 'GOOGL';
    let url = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol=${stockSymbol}&apikey=${apiKey}`;

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(json => {
        return me._flattenData(json);
      })
      .then(jsonflatRows => {
        me._renderChart(jsonflatRows);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("error", err);
      })
  }

  /**
   * The goal is to flatten the nested json data, so it's easy to consume in the charts.
   * @param json data
   * @returns {*[]} array of json data
   * @private
   */
  _flattenData(json) {
    console.log("json=", json);

    let jsonTimes = json['Monthly Time Series']

    let flatRows = [];

    for (let jsonTime in jsonTimes) {
      let row = {
        "time": jsonTime
      };

      let jsonNestedTime = jsonTimes[jsonTime];

      for (let nestedKey in jsonNestedTime) {
        row[nestedKey] = jsonNestedTime[nestedKey];
      }

      flatRows.push(row);
    }

    return flatRows.reverse();
  }

  _renderChart(jsonflatRows) {
    console.log('_renderChart jsonflatRows=', jsonflatRows);

    let store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      fields: ["time", "1. open", "2. high", "3. low", "4. close", "5. volume"]
    });
    store.loadData(jsonflatRows);

    let areaChartEl = this.querySelector('ext-cartesian');
    areaChartEl.ext.bindStore(store);
  }

}
window.customElements.define('my-chart-area', AreaChartComponent);
```

**Source**

https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/4652a5d7188dfe0b33d3d02a808d8d74